# How can I know what www-data can do on my /var/www folder?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

When I run `ls -l` on the `www` folder and everything that's inside, I see that root:root are the owner/group

When I run `ps aux | grep apache2`, I get the first process owned by root (I assume this is normal, but why is it owned by root and not www-data?) and I get 6 other processes owned by www-data.

Now, since the `ls -l /var/www` shows `-rw-r--r--`, it should mean that `www-data` has no write privileges since it's in "world" (and also not in the "root" group).

But if, in my web application, users can upload images, I imagine there should be a folder inside `/www` called "uploadedpics/" on which `www-data` would have write privileges, is that right?

So if user and group are `root:root` for the `/www` folder, how can I create a subdirectory in which `www-data` can write?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Apache process being owned by root is an artifact of earlier days of computing on Linux where the root user was the only account which can bind to ports under 1024. The progresses that serve content run under the www user.

To allow write access to a folder change the owner or group to the www user and chmod 775 or similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So would that mean that the permission of subdirectory would take precedence over permissions of parent folder? Thanks

Comment: @eric01 - yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the new folder group to www-data (`sudo chgrp www-data <your-folder>`) and give w permission to the group (`sudo chmod g+w <your-folder>`).

Another way (wich I prefer) is to use ACLs (`man setfacl` for more details if you want to go that way).